# Image serial is not maintaining in OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, glob

Using OpenCV I have read all the images of a folder then converted it into grayscale and then I have saved all the converted images to a new folder which name is `"binary image"`. But when I again read all the images from the `"binary image"` folder to show histogram then the serial of images in `"binary image"` folder is not maintaining. Instead of image number 12th, the histogram is showing is 19th number image in the folder. But the total number of histograms are good as it is supposed to be. How can I maintain serial of images?

How i read images:

```
images1=[cv2.imread(file) for file in glob.glob(r"C:\Users\USER\Handcrafted dataset\binary_image/*.jpg")]
```

thats how i save histogram image:

```
 dir1=r"C:\Users\USER\Handcrafted dataset\histogram"
for i,img in enumerate(images1):
    plt.figure(figsize=(5,5))
    plt.hist(img.ravel(),256,[0,256],label=str(np.mean(img)))
    plt.legend(loc="upper right")
    plt.savefig(dir1+"\\"+str(i)+".png")
    print(i)

    plt.show()
```

to save gray scale image:

```
di=r"C:\Users\USER\Handcrafted dataset\binary_image"
for i,img in enumerate(images):
    img = rgb2gray(img)
    plt.figure(figsize=(5,5))
    print(i)
    plt.imshow(img ,cmap='gray')
    io.imsave(di+"\\"+str(i)+".jpg",img)
```

at first when I read images then the image name was random but after converting into grayscale I have saved the images in `"binary image"` folder as renaming from 0 to 51. That means `0.jpg, 1.jpg` serially. After that to show histogram I have used the binay_image folder where images were sorted as I mentioned before. but histogram is showing randomly.

Comment: how do you save 'em ?

Comment: @lenik please check! i have modified the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, here's a problem. When you use `glob.glob()` file names come in no specific order. That is, unless you sort them yourself or do something about the order, you cannot assume the file `001.jpg` coming before `002.jpg`.

So, when you `enumerate(images1)` -- the results will be like you described. The numbers and file names won't match.

What you can do, the simplest is to add `sorted()` to the file list:

```
images1=[cv2.imread(file) for file in sorted(glob.glob(r"C:\Users\..."))]
```

This however assumes your files are properly numbered without files missing in between, like `006` and then `010` with `007`, `008` and `009` missing.

---

UPDATE: once I saw the file names: `0.jpg, 1.jpg` I immediately know what the problem is. File names are sorted lexicographically, that is, 1, 10, 11, 12, ... 2, 20, 21, 22 -- I hope you catch my drift...

When you name your files, please, add leading zeros, they are there for a reason, to keep your files in the order, instead of:

```
plt.savefig(dir1+"\\"+str(i)+".png")
```

use:

```
plt.savefig(os.path.join( dir1, "%06d.png" % i))
```

Comment: @imtinan please, add to the question the sample list of the input and output file names your have and output file names your want to have? this will greatly simplify things. thanks!

Comment: please check @lenik